# Restrict access to website in test environment for a client (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis

I have an ASP.NET website that is deployed to a test server. I want to share this website with a client of mine, but not with the public yet as that website instance is intended only for testing and client feedback, might contain bugs, various test data, unfinished features, etc.

### What are some common methods to achieve this?

---

#### My previous solution

Previously I've done it in a way that I enabled "Basic Authentication" on IIS on the website and created credentials for the client to use. But now my website is using ASP.NET Identity and has both stuff for guests and registered users. And it's not possible to use ASP.NET Identity together with other form of authentication set up in IIS.

#### My ideas

1. I know that I could maybe set up a firewall and restrict access by IP address, but this will fail if the client will want to test the website using different IP addresses often or if he has a dynamic IP.
2. Other solution that comes to my mind is VPN, but I have little to no experience with how to set it up on my Azure servers, and I hope there might be some simpler solution I could develop.
3. I am thinking of developing some simple layer on top of all the ASP.NET authentication stuff that will not interfere with all the `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` stuff built-in ASP.NET for authentication. But I am not sure if there aren't some better alternatives.

#### Security concerns

I'm not that concerned about having the highest security there. The URL of the test website instance is not public, so potential attacker would have to discover the URL first. And in the worst case scenario, he/she will only get access to the test version of the website as an unauthenticated user, which is not a huge security risk. However, I still believe that I could implement a secure-enough solution if necessary.

*Any ideas are welcome. I tried searching Google, but couldn't find much (maybe wrong keywords?)*

*Thanks.*

Comment: did  you tried using authorization. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx So that if some one want to access they have to enter the user name and password provided by you. for example try to access below url: http://api.ziro.sigmasolve.net/api/customer/login It will ask you for user name and passowrd

Comment: @VenkateshKonatham: That mechanism doesn't work together with ASP.NET Identity that I use for guests / user registration on the website itself. I'd like so that the client could access the website both as a guest and as a registered user, but only the client, not the public. And both of the guest/registered user and authorization use the same mechanism in ASP.NET and fight with each other.

Comment: This question is off-topic, as you're asking for product recommendations, references, links, etc. And it really is broad and opinion-based. Having said that: You've already come up with the two primary ways of restricting access (VPN and IP-whitelisting). Beyond that, not sure what you're going to be able to do (and honestly, I don't see why IP-whitelisting would be an issue, esp when you're trying to restrict access).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Hi David, thanks for the response. Is there a stackexchange site that's more on-topic for the question? I'm thinking that with VPN and IP-whitelisting it can be an issue if I have multiple websites of multiple clients on the same server.

Comment: IPSecurity feature of IIS would be easiest and quickest one to configure where you can provide access to IP range.